# c# Regex replace punctuation with space and matching braces with comma

Tags: c#, regex

I have an Form data with punctuation and matching parenthesis. I need to replace punctuation with space and matching braces with comma. Also need to make sure the final result doesn't have multiple spaces.

For Example:

```
*fName   *   -sName!lName(London)
```

should be

```
fName sName lName, London
```

Was trying to have three regex and replace them in order

```
static string BracePattern = @"[()]";
static string PuncPattern = @"[^\w\,]";
static string SpacePattern = @"\s+";
res1 = Regex.Replace(formData, BracePattern, ",");
res2 = Regex.Replace(res1, PuncPattern , ",");
res3 = Regex.Replace(res2, SpacePattern , ",").trim();
```

My final result is :

```
fName sName lName,London,
```

Still cant get. I know there is one regex to solve this. But cant get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace your bracket pattern you need to add a capturing group for the content between opening and closing brackets and use this in the function that returns the replacement value:

```
 var replacedBrackets = Regex.Replace(res1,
    @"\((?'content'[^)]+)\)", match => $", {match.Groups["content"].Value}");
```

You could also add a `+` to your `PuncPattern` to replace a range of 'punctuation' characters with a single space - this would avoid having to normalise the space in your third replacement.

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BloIIK) for a working demo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "*fName   *   -sName!lName(London) ";
            string pattern = @"(?'word'\w+)";

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

            string output = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}, {3}",
                matches[0].Groups["word"].Value,
                matches[1].Groups["word"].Value,
                matches[2].Groups["word"].Value,
                matches[3].Groups["word"].Value
                );
            Console.WriteLine(output);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a non-regex answer, you can:

1. Split the input string by multiple punctuation characters
2. `Trim()` all the tokens
3. Remove empty string tokens
4. Retrieve the last string token
5. Remove last string token from the list
6. Append the last string token to the result with `,`

Code:

```
string line = @"*fName   *   -sName!lName(London) ";

var tokens = line.Split(new char[] { '*', '-', '!', '(', ')' })
                    .Select(s => s.Trim())
                    .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.Trim()))
                    .ToList();
string last = tokens.Last();
tokens.RemoveAt(tokens.Count - 1);
string result = String.Join(" ", tokens) + ", " + last;
```